# Cross browser solution for checking Null Iframes

Tags: javascript

I am struggling since quite a long time now, and finally I have to post a query since I havent received any relevant answer till now.

What I need is to check for Null Iframes and accordingly call a function. I am looking for a replacement for the below three lines of code so as to be able to work in all browsers rather than only in IE.

```
if (this.document.frames != null ) {
    for (var i=0;i<this.document.frames.length;i++){
        if (this.document.frames[i] != null ) {
```

PS: I cannot use getElementbyId or getElementsByTagName since the IFrames in my code are created dynamically. 
Sorry for my knowledge,but I am preety new to Javascript and seem to have tried too many things now :(

Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: If the iframes are created dynamically, why don't you save them in a global array? However, this only works if you're using `document.createElement`. Add an example of your problem to your question, a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) would be wonderful (you can use http://jsfiddle to post your example).

Comment: What are all the `"` characters doing?

Comment: @Pekka i think the OP is referring to document.getElementById returning `null` if no element is found.

Comment: @ Rob, Pekka :Sorry, I think I led to loads of confusions by saying Null Iframes. I am trying to check if there are more Iframes in my window and accordingly I am calling a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [getElementbyId](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) and [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) for dynamically added elements as long as you look for the elements AFTER they have been added to the DOM.

To put it another way, you can only find them if they exist at that point in time you look for them.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'); // notice this is not 'frame'

var length = iframes.length;
var currentIFrame;
var counter;

for (counter = 0; counter < length; counter += 1) {
    currentIFrame = iframes[counter];

    // do stuff with currentIFrame
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fuEsw/

Comment: Thanks jbabey for your help. But I am trying to use this functionality for my SAP Portal. To brief, I have a function ABC()  that really looks for frames in the page. Recursive function that search for frames in the document. It´s recursive to search for frames inside the frames. In case the page has not loaded 100, this function could return errors, this is why it contains a try-catch routine ignoring the errors.For every iFrame found the onmouseup event is added as follows:this.document.body.onmouseup = updateStatus;

Comment: @archanachaubey this is an entirely different question than what you have posted. i would suggest asking a new question and provide the information in this comment in addition to what you have tried so far.